# Fitting a 3D GMM in a 3D space is equivalent to fit a gaussian in each 1D coordinate?

Tags: normal-distribution, fitting, generalized-moments

I have a 3D data set data represents positions in X,Y,Z space. The positions are generated by a Poisson model. I would like to filter out outlier positions, i.e., positions that are farther than the estimated center given a certain criterion.  What I do now is to fit the projections of the positions to a 1D Gaussian and filter it based on how many standard deviations farther from the mean they are. So, there is a filtering in X, Y, and Z. Is this equivalent to fit the data to a 3D Gaussian Mixture Model, compute the center and filter based on its projected standard deviation?

---

**EDIT**: here is a more precise description of the first method:

We are given a dataset $\mathcal D$ of $N$ points in $\mathbb R^3$ described as $$\mathcal D = \{(x_1,y_1,z_1),\dots,(x_N,y_N,z_N)\}$$ The objective is to detect outliers in $\mathcal D$, and the first proposed method is:

1. For each point $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ in $\mathcal D$, compute
   \begin{align}
   x_i &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_i \\ y_i \\ z_i\end{bmatrix} \\
   y_i &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_i \\ y_i \\ z_i\end{bmatrix} \\
   z_i &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_i \\ y_i \\ z_i\end{bmatrix} 
   \end{align}
2. Store the individual coordinates $x_i,y_i,$ and $z_i$ obtained in step 1 into the new datasets $\mathcal D_x,\mathcal D_y,$ and $\mathcal D_z$.
3. For each of the datasets $\mathcal D_x,\mathcal D_y,$ and $\mathcal D_z$, estimate the mean and standard deviation using (for example) the sample mean $\hat\mu$ and sample standard deviation $\hat\sigma$. These will respectively be denoted as $\hat\mu_x,\hat\mu_y,\hat\mu_z$ and $\hat\sigma_x,\hat\sigma_y,\hat\sigma_z$.
4. For each coordinate $x_i$ in $\mathcal D_x$, compute the distance $d_{x_i} = \frac{x_i - \hat\mu_x}{\hat\sigma_x}$. If $|d_{x_i}|$ is greater than some threshold, then reject the point $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ as an outlier. Otherwise, for each coordinate $y_i$ in $\mathcal D_y$, compute the distance $d_{y_i} = \frac{y_i - \hat\mu_y}{\hat\sigma_y}$. If $|d_{y_i}|$ is greater than some threshold, then reject the point $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ as an outlier. Repeat this logic for $\mathcal D_z$.

**EDIT**: second method:
We are given a dataset $\mathcal D$ of $N$ points in $\mathbb R^3$ described as $$\mathcal D = \{(x_1,y_1,z_1),\dots,(x_N,y_N,z_N)\}$$ The objective is to detect outliers in $\mathcal D$, and the first proposed method is:

1. Fit a 3D Gaussian Mixture Model with one component to $\mathcal D$.
2. The model estimates the means in each coordinate, denoted as $\hat\mu_x,\hat\mu_y,\hat\mu_z$ and the covariance matrix, denoted as:
   covariance $\Sigma$ = \begin{bmatrix} \hat\sigma_{xx} & \hat\sigma_{xy}& \hat\sigma_{xz}\\   \hat\sigma_{yx} &\hat\sigma_{yy} & \hat\sigma_{yz}\\ \hat\sigma_{zx} & \hat\sigma_{zy}& \hat\sigma_{zz}\end{bmatrix}
3. For each point $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ in $\mathcal D$ compute the Mahalanobis distance to the distribution with means $\hat\mu_x,\hat\mu_y,\hat\mu_z$ and
   covariance $\Sigma$. If the distance is greater than some threshold, then reject the point $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ as an outlier.

Comment: Just to confirm, given a set of $N$ 3D points $(x,y,z)$, you are proposing to split this dataset into three separate datasets, one each for the three coordinates. Then, for each dataset, you fit a 1D Gaussian, and then use this fitted Gaussian to check outliers in each of the coordinates. If so, what happens if a point is an outlier for one coordinate, but is not an outlier for another? What do you do in this case?

Comment: In this case it will be deleted from all coordinates.

Comment: I've added what I think is a more precise description of your first method. I'm not sure if it's what you meant. If not, please [edit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/610457/edit) your question to include the right information. Also, please add a more specific description of your second method.

Comment: I suspect the answer to your question ("is it equivalent") is no, because a mixture model in higher (more than one) dimension can allow for correlation, whereas your proposed approach effectively assumes independence.

Comment: Welcome to CV. It is very unclear how and why you would be applying Gaussian models or Gaussian mixture models to positions generated by some kind of multivariate *Poisson* distribution.  The difference between these families of distributions could have a profound effect on what might be considered an "outlier."  I am therefore at a loss to understand what you are doing or why.

Comment: Thank you for the edit @mhdadk. I also attempted to add a better description of method 2.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Adrian. Maybe I can also reformulate my question as: are  $\hat\sigma_x,\hat\sigma_y,\hat\sigma_z$ equivalent to $\hat\sigma_{xx},\hat\sigma_{yy},\hat\sigma_{zz}$ ? (Given the information on the edit question.)